# How to grep for two characters at specific file position

Tags: grep

I need to grep a file for 2 consecutive characters at a specific position in a file. I can grep for a single character using (in this example I'm grepping for the number 1):

```
grep -E '^.{50}[1]' file.txt
```

This searches the first character, but I have no idea how to check the 2nd character.
The 2 characters are a timestamp and I need to search for hours 18 through 23, and 00 through 06.
Any help, as always, appreciated :)

Comment: it would be nice if you have posted the input string and expected output

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an hour which is in the set (18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23), you want to use the "|" operator inside a set of parenthesis:

```
grep -E '^.{50}(18|19|20|21|22|23)' file.txt
```

This would match ANY of the patterns in the '|' delimited list beginning in the 51st character of the line.

To check for two repeated digits at the 51st and 52nd offset, try:

`grep -E '^.{50}([0-9])\1' file.txt`

The back reference (\1) here says "match the pattern encosed by the first set of parenthesis".  In this case, if you had 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, and 23 in different lines of your, file, only the lines containing 11 and 22 would match.  The [0-9] limits it to digits, and the \1 says match the first digit.